# c# Convert from dynamic object (that has been converted from a JSON string) back into a DataTable

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I am looping through a collection of dynamic objects, and each object began as a DataTable somewhere else, was converted to Json, then Json into dynamic, and now I'm wanting to convert it back into a DataTable.

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
{
    "TRS_KEY": 1716,
    "TRS_PTR": 54,
    "PLUID": 9314807005306,
    "Ext11": false,
    "Subtract": false,
    "Cancel": false,
    "Negative": false,
    "FuelItemCancel": false,
    "StaffDiscAllow": true,
    "PriceOveride": false,
    "OnSale": false,
    "WSPriceOverride": false,
    "ManPrice": false,
    "ManPriceAllw": false,
    "NoManWgnt": false,
    "WgtItem": false,
    "DecItem": false,
    "Gallons": false,
    "ChainPrv": false,
    "NonMerch": false,
    "StoreCpn": false,
    "VendorCpn": false,
    "DiscAlw": true,
    "Scan": false,
    "ReadSrv": null,
    "NextInfo": false,
    "ReplUnknown": false,
    "GSTExclFollow": false,
    "PriceGrid": false,
    "DepID": 1070,
    "MSU": 1,
    "RetnID": 0,
    "TaxF": 16,
    "QTY": 1,
    "Price": 8,
    "Amount": 8,
    "ExclPrice": 8,
    "ExclAmount": 7.27,
    "CaseQty": false,
    "TailFlags": 0,
    "NoStockDeduct": false,
    "NoLoyaltyPoints": false
}

]
```

The method is as follows: (dynamicTatble is the dynamic object holding the JSON data)

```
foreach (dynamic dynamicTable in dynMessage.SourceData)
                    {
                        context.Logger.Log($"table -> {dynMessage.TableReference.IncludedTables[tableIndex].ToString()} outer -> {dynamicTable}");

                        string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynamicTable);
                        DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s, (typeof(DataTable)));
                        context.Logger.LogLine($"DataTableRows={dt.Rows.Count}");

                        tableIndex++;
                    }
```

I am trying to convert from dynamic to JSON string, then JSON string to DataTable but am getting the following error:

> One or more errors occurred. (Cannot deserialize the current JSON
>   array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Data.DataTable' because the
>   type requires a JSON object (e.g. {
>       "name": "value" } ) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {
>       "name": "value" } ) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection,
>   IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1.):
>   AggregateException at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32
>   millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )
>
> at lambdaS2CProcessMessage.Function.FunctionHandler(SQSEvent evnt,
>   ILambdaContext context) in
>   C:\Users\jmatson\Source\Repos\AWS-S2C-ProcessMessage\lambdaS2CProcessMessage\Function.cs:line
>   154

Comment: I think the Log is self-explanatory. You are Passing an Array to convert while it needs an object..

Comment: yip - that ain't any json i seen before

Comment: Crap, I just noticed the brackets... so is it just a case of referencing the index of the array in the conversion to a DataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should try This. The Thing that you are doing wrong is that you are Trying to Convert an Array of Objects to a single Object. You Should Either Remove the Starting and Ending `[` `]` from your Json String.

```
foreach (dynamic dynamicTable in dynMessage.SourceData)
{
    context.Logger.Log($"table -> {dynMessage.TableReference.IncludedTables[tableIndex].ToString()} outer -> {dynamicTable}");

    string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynamicTable);
    s = s.Trim().TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']');

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s, (typeof(DataTable)));
    context.Logger.LogLine($"DataTableRows={dt.Rows.Count}");

    tableIndex++;
}
```

Alternatively, If your Data Is Going to be List of Something, then Simple Convert it to List of Something.. `List<Something>` like:

```
var dat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Something>>(s);
```

Comment: Thank you. So I'm guessing if that JSON can sometimes contain more than one array element (in my example its only one, but some will contain multiple array elements) then I should use your second example?

Comment: @JamesMatson No. Json Can Contain an Object, or an Array Of Objects but not Multiple Arrays.

Comment: @JamesMatson, If this Answers your Question, then please mark it as Correct Answer..

Comment: I’m yet to test the code out, once I’ve done that if it solves the problem I’ll mark the question answered of course.